# Hat Check Bernoulli Trials (Just Need Answers Checked)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Experiment X denotes the three hat experiment, where all outcomes are equally likely.

1. If you do X 7 times, what is the probability that person 1 gets his own hat on at least 5 of them?
2. If you do X 18 times, what is the expected number times that both person 1 and person 2 get their own hats.
3. What is the probability that the first derangement occurs on the 5th time X is performed?
4. What is the expected wait for a derangement?
5. What is the probability that person 1 failed to get his own hat for the third time on the 6th performance of X?

Comment: I have posted some of the answers I got, if someone could please double check them.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Success on one experiment - $\frac{1}{3}$

Getting success on at least 5 = $(\frac{1}{3})^5$

Getting something else = ($\frac{2}{3})^5$

Answer: $1-((\frac{2}{3})^5)^7$

(2) Success on one expirement - $\frac{1}{6}$

Answer: $E$(person 1 & 2) = $18S$ = $\frac{18}{6}$ = $3$

(3) Probability of Derangement - $\frac{1}{3}$

Wait for first success = $5X$

Answer: $(\frac{2}{3})^4(\frac{1}{3})$

(4) Wait Time: $P(S) = (\frac{1}{3}) $

$E(W) = \frac{1}{P(S)} = (\frac{1}{1/3}) = 3 $

(5) Used negative binomial frequency function

$P(W_3 = 6) =$ $6 \choose 2 $$(\frac{2}{3})^3(\frac{1}{3})^3$